# redirect following in cucumber howto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have a scenario of a feature like this

```
Scenario: can't find similar movies if we don't know director (sad path)
Given I am on the details page for "Alien"
Then  I should not see "Ridley Scott"
When  I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"
Then  I should be on the home page
Then   I should see "'Alien' has no director info"
```

I have a controller action for **'Find Movies With Same Director'** named find_by_same_director and also have a view template with the same name, but when a movie does not have a director similar movies should take to home page, i do it in the controller action in this way..

```
def find_by_same_director
 m = Movie.find params[:id]
 @similar_movies = m.similar_movies
 if @similar_movies.count == 0
   flash[:notice] = "#{m.title} has no director info"
   render :index
 end
end
```

And in paths.rb path_to method has 'the home page' case as this

```
when /^the home\s?page$/
  movies_path
```

To pass the step *Then  I should be on the home page* what should i be doing ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would drop the '^' and '$' in the home page path RE since they are not anchored there.

"Then I should be on the home page" should be picked up in the web_steps.rb and finding the step in there. Specifically the step:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  current_path = URI.parse(current_url).path                                                                                                                                                                                               
  if current_path.respond_to? :should                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    current_path.should == path_to(page_name)                                                                                                                                                                                              
  else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    assert_equal path_to(page_name), current_path                                                                                                                                                                                          
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
end
```

Also, you have to be careful about spaces in the string or after it.  (spaces between Given/When/Then and the start of your string shouldn't matter.)